# Python executable created using pyinstaller will no longer run with dependant packages

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyinstaller, executable

I have a program written in python that is exported to a raspberry pi to run. I tested the .py file in the raspberry pi to verify that it works, then used pyinstaller to make a --onefile copy of the .py file as an executable. When I attempt to run the executable, I get an error that states no module named tkinter.

```
ImportError: no module named tkinter
```

I had problems before using pyinstaller on an x86 computer and trying to port to the raspi, but I compiled on the raspi and avoided that issue, now it just seems like I am not freezing all the packages like it is supposed to. To make the executable, I ran the following:

```
pyinstaller --onefile bar_3axis.py
```

Any help would be appreciated. Do I need to post complete readout from pyinstaller command?

Comment: Might need to explicitly include the package in your setup file.  (?)  Some packages are not auto-included as they should be and need to be explicitly included.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would like everyone to know it was because my program was written in and supported by python3 packages and I downloaded and was using pyinstaller that used python 2.7 to make the executable. I uninstalled pyinstaller and redownloaded using pip3 and it worked like a charm.